# How to extract data from a databse and into E.g a Label editbox?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, delphi-7

I got a Label3 and a richedit where I want to show information on. I want the information from a database (Specificly from the table - Candidate_table). Candidate table has these Columns :

Name * Surname * Grade * Service_Points * Slogan * Description

There will be exactly 5 candidates , so each column will be filled out 5 times.

So here is what I want to do:

Whenever I click on the combobox the 5 candidate's names will display. When I cick on a Specific name E.g John I want his slogan to display on the Label3 and his Description in the Richedit1.

So I am trying this (onchange) :

case DBCombox1.Itemindex of 0 : begin

Candidate_table.Fieldbyname('Name').asString := DBCombobox1.text[0];

Adoquery1.active := false;

Adoquery.sql.text := 'Select Slogan, Description from candidate table where name = Candidate_table.Fieldbyname('Slogan').asString;

adoquery1.active := true;

label3.caption := Candidate_table.Fieldbyname('Slogan').asString ;

Richedit1.lines.add(Candidate_table.Fieldbyname('Description').asString) ;

end;

So this is'nt working...

Can i do this what I want or should I change my form >?[image]

Comment: This is getting old. "So this is'nt working" is not a description o a problem. You need to explain what isn't working if you want us to help you. And what's wrong with a `TDBText` and `TDBMemo`, that will do this for you automatically (and are designed for exactly this purpose)? (And please learn how to format your code. You can get help to do so by clicking the little orange `?` at the top right of the area you're typing your question, and you even get to preview it as you're formatting by looking right below the text area.)

Comment: Wait. You've already asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18657069/62576). Please don't post the same question over and over. If you're not getting answers, edit your question and improve it. The [help] tells you what to do if you're not getting answers. Posting intentional duplicates is against the rules here. Please don't do it.